# Ascii-Doc Maven Plugin (include resources via https)

Tags: java, maven, asciidoctor

Is there a way to configure the asciidoc-maven-plugin to include https-resources? I did some research and found the follwing (interesting) information, however, was not able to solve the problem according to the hints provided:

- https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1049
- https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-maven-plugin/issues/153

The latter link seemed to adress the exact problem I have, however, upgrading / changing versions did not have any effect.

The following pom.xml file is a minimum working example that allows you to replicate the problem:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version>2.2.1</asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version>
    <asciidoctorj.diagram.version>2.2.0</asciidoctorj.diagram.version>
    <asciidoctorj.version>2.5.2</asciidoctorj.version>
    <jruby.version>9.2.17.0</jruby.version>
  </properties>

  <build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
        <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${asciidoctor.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>output-html5</id> 
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirectory>src/main/docs</sourceDirectory>
              <outputDirectory>target/docs</outputDirectory>
              <backend>html5</backend>
              <doctype>book</doctype>
              <attributes>
                <safe-mode>UNSAFE</safe-mode>
                <allow-uri-read>true</allow-uri-read>
              </attributes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
            <version>${asciidoctorj.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
            <artifactId>jruby-complete</artifactId>
            <version>${jruby.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    
  </build>
  
</project>
```

Now, if I save the following .adoc-file to the `src/main/docs` folder and run `mvn clean install`, I just get a notice *Unresolved directive in my-project.adoc - include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/master/README.adoc* instead of the actual document:

```
= my-project
include::https://raw.githubusercontent.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/master/README.adoc[]
```

However, if I donwload the above document (README.adoc) and reference it locally, I get the desired result. But this is not the way I want to include documentation by first downloading the file and then referencing it locally.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to only manage a single Maven project that contains all documentation including documentation from related projects that are also in our Gitlab repository. That is why I wanted to reference .adoc-files in those related projects by using `include::https://concreteURLToAdocFile`.

However, we realized, that it is a better idea to use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to first copy the .adoc-files from the other projects and then reference them locally.

This solution solved our concrete problem, however, it did not answer my original question.